# relation between a curve's function and it's tangent (from graph)

Tags: calculus

The figure attached represents the curve of the function $y = f(x) $, if the equation of the tangent to the curve at any point $(x,y)$ on it is $y=g(x)$ so the following statement is correct ...

[image: graph plot of the curve]

choices:

a) $g(x) = f(x)$ 
b) $g(x) \le f(x)$ 
c) $g(x) \ge f(x)$ 
b) $g(x) + f(x) \lt 0$

The correct answer is C but i need explanation for that please.

Comment: There is no figure attached.

Comment: uploading please wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans C is correct if the function $y=f(x)$ is convex. This is one of the properties of convex functions (see section 2.4 in [link](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt/scribes/02-convex-fns-scribed.pdf)).For illustration purposes, see figure below

[image]

As you can see in the plot, function always lies above the tangent at any point. Hence, option c is correct. 
For concave functions, b is correct ans.

Comment: Yes it's a convex curve, that clarifies it!

Comment: The function in your plot is concave since function always lies `below` the tangent at any point. Whereas, the function in my example plot is convex, by definition.

Comment: I found that C was switched with B i corrected them .. So in your function the correct answer is that function of the tangent always $ \le $ the curve's function right?

Comment: it's corrected now, my fault ! धन्यवाद

Comment: In my plot, function clearly lies `above` the tangent at any point. You are welcome.